# Details section continue data next columns crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have the following kind of table

```
Name        Id        Desig
Srikanth    1         SSE
Sridhar     2         SE
Srinath     3         SE   
Srikanth    1         SSE
Sridhar     2         SE
Srinath     3         SE   
Srikanth    1         SSE
Sridhar     2         SE
Srinath     3         SE   
Srikanth    1         SSE
Sridhar     2         SE
Srinath     3         SE   
Srikanth    1         SSE
Sridhar     2         SE
Srinath     3         SE   
Srikanth    1         SSE
Sridhar     2         SE
Srinath     3         SE   
Srikanth    1         SSE
Sridhar     2         SE
Srinath     3         SE
```

I want to format the above table data in such a way that after 6th record data has to continue display in next column like following

```
Name        ID       Desig        Name        ID       Desig        Here Next tables rows
Srikanth    1         SSE          Sridhar     2         SE
Srinath     3         SE           Srikanth    1         SSE
Sridhar     2         SE           Srinath     3         SE   
Srikanth    1         SSE          Sridhar     2         SE
Srinath     3         SE           Srikanth    1         SSE
Sridhar     2         SE           Srinath     3         SE
```

Any workaround in Crystal reports?

Comment: Srikanth for your query, I will suggest that you should used CROSS Tab report for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to format your report to display multiple columns.  One 'column' will be size to display your 3 fields.  For instructions, see my reply to [Crystal Reports putting a group in different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997617/crystal-reports-putting-a-group-in-different-columns).

It will be a challenge to get formatting to work after the Nth row.  I'll research it a bit and post an update.

** edit **

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any way to force CR to create a new column (in a multi-column report) other than to change the page size.  In File | Page Setup..., I set the Vertical property to 1.6"--your setting will probably be different.

Answer (score 0):

You could arrange the data inside a subreport, constrained to the height you want, and configured for multiple columns.